# Public & Private REST APIs with Spring Security

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a REST Web Service written with Spring 3.2 that is secured with CAS via Spring Security, and I would like to have it provide an identical private, internal API that could be consumed by other servers on our private network without requiring authentication.

For example, these two endpoints `/app/public/people/{id}` and `/app/private/people/{id}` would both map to the same handler but the latter would bypass security and the former would require CAS authentication.

Can I just put both in the same `@RequestMapping` annotation and specify different security intercepts?  For example,

security intercepts:

```
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/private/**" access="permitAll() />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/public/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https"/>
```

request mapping:
`@RequestMapping(value={"/public/people/{id}", "/private/people/{id}"})`

Answer (score 3):

What about using IP address to distinguish between access from private and public network? Then you can define just one endpoint for both. For an example, if you’re private network is 192.168.1.0/24, then:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
          access="isAuthenticated() or hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')"
          requires-channel="https" />
```

If you have Servlet container behind a reverse proxy, don’t forget to set `X-Forwarded-For` (or `X-Real-IP`) header and configure your container to use it; otherwise Spring Security will see IP of the reverse proxy, not a client.